# SCP in ESXi not working

Tags: ssh, vmware, scp, esxi

Everytime I try to copy files from ESXi machine to other Linux machine it always fails. Either it waits for longer time or ends up with time out error.

Cmd used: scp local_file root@:IP:path/to/folder

cmd err:ssh: connect to host port 22: Connection timed out
lost connection

Linux machine has sshd service running.

But, copying from Linux to ESXi works.

Where am I missing in configuration? Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable sshClient in the firewall properties of the server.

In vSphere Client select

`host -> Configuration -> Security Profile -> Firewall -> Properties`

then enable `SSH Client` to enable outgoing scp connections.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! It worked. I was not knowing we have separate ports for outgoing scp connections.

Comment: in later vSphere networking > firewall rules > enable (was clicking everywhere looking for this)

Comment: This isn't supported in latest version of vSphere so please use command line.

Answer (score 15):

Enable SSH client (CLI method).

Check if SSH client service is enabled. Will return 'False' if 'Disabled'.

`esxcli network firewall ruleset list --ruleset-id sshClient`

Then enable SSH client.

`esxcli network firewall ruleset set --ruleset-id sshClient --enabled=true`